# How to add the crosswalk plugin in cordova android project?

Tags: android, cordova, crosswalk

I want to add crosswalk project to my old cordova android project it is throwing the error like crosswalk classes can't be casted to webview and how to run javascript in crosswalk webview?

Comment: check it here 
https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/cordova/cordova_3/add_plugins.html

Comment: Thanks Usman Kurd but how can i inject javascript into the crosswalk any idea ?